AVX(2)/SIMD way to get/set (to 1) a single bit in a 256 bit register
Current but hacky approach is this:
__m256i bitset(__m256i source, uint8_t index) {
    uint8_t pos_in_64 = index % 64;
    uint8_t location = index / 64;
    uint64_t bitmask = 1ULL << pos_in_64;

    __m256i mask = _mm256_setzero_si256();
    switch (location) {
    case 0: mask = _mm256_set_epi64x(0, 0, 0, bitmask); break;
    case 1: mask = _mm256_set_epi64x(0, 0, bitmask, 0); break;
    case 2: mask = _mm256_set_epi64x(0, bitmask, 0, 0); break;
    case 3: mask = _mm256_set_epi64x(bitmask, 0, 0, 0); break;
    }

    return _mm256_or_si256(source, mask);
}

bool bitget(__m256i source, uint8_t index) {
    uint8_t pos_in_64 = index % 64;
    uint8_t location = index / 64;
    uint64_t bitmask = 1ULL << pos_in_64;

    uint64_t extracted = 0;
    switch (location) {
    case 0: extracted = _mm256_extract_epi64(source, 0); break;
    case 1: extracted = _mm256_extract_epi64(source, 1); break;
    case 2: extracted = _mm256_extract_epi64(source, 2); break;
    case 3: extracted = _mm256_extract_epi64(source, 3); break;
    }
    return (extracted & bitmask) != 0;
}

But I'm sure there's a saner way to implement this without the switch statements and loads of scalar code

Is index likely to be a compile-time constant?

Also, is the result likely to be used for a branch, or an input to a vectorized function, or something else?

@NateEldredge index isn't known at comp time, in the case of bitget it will be used in a branch to check if said bit is set (and if its not set it using bitset)
e.g.
static __m256i x = _mm256_setzero_si256();
//inside a func
if (!bitget(x, y)) {x = setbit(x, y);}

But that code seems better done branchlessly as x = _mm256_or_si256(x, setbit(0, y))

So this might be an XY problem; your micro-optimization might be a little too micro.  It might help to step back and look at the broader context in which you need this.

there are some steps in the function besides setting the bit if its not set so I in this case need to know the actual return of bitget

What other steps? I don't think there's anything wrong with discussing bare bitset and bitget but depending on the context there may be opportunities to do something else, such as if you were scanning for the lowest unset bit and then setting it there's a loop-free trick for that and so on.

"Bit Test and Set" can be implemented with setbit() and vptest. However, just because a vector register has 256-bits doesn't mean it is good for bitset operations...

See set individual bit in AVX register (__m256i), need "random access" operator for the set operation.

I would do it like that.
#include <stdint.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

namespace
{
    // Shift the bits of unsigned 64-bit integer "a" left by the number of bits specified in "shift", 
    // rotating the most-significant bit to the least-significant bit location
    inline uint64_t rotateLeft( uint64_t value, int shift )
    {
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
        // _rotl64 for MSVC and Intel compilers
        return _rotl64( value, shift );
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
        // __rolq for gcc compiler
        return __rolq( value, shift );
#elif defined(__clang__)
        // __builtin_rotateleft64 for clang compiler
        return __builtin_rotateleft64( value, shift );
#else
        // Fallback for weird compilers
        return ( value << shift ) | ( value >> ( 64 - shift ) );
#endif  
    }

    // Make int32 vector [ v, 0, 0, 0, U, U, U, U ] where U = undefined
    inline __m256i setLow( uint32_t v )
    {
        return _mm256_castsi128_si256( _mm_cvtsi32_si128( (int)v ) );
    }
}

inline __m256i makeSingleBitMask( uint8_t index )
{
    // Make a vector with single bit in the lowest int32 lane
    const __m256i vec32 = setLow( 1u << ( index % 32 ) );

    // Compute left shift amount
    // The formula is ( index / 32 ) * 8, saving one bit shift instruction there
    const uint8_t shift = ( index & (uint8_t)0b11100000 ) >> 2;

    // Create permutation vector for vpermd instruction
    const uint64_t perm8s = rotateLeft( 0x0101010101010100ull, shift );
    const __m128i perm8v = _mm_cvtsi64_si128( perm8s );
    const __m256i perm32 = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi32( perm8v );

    // Produce the vector
    return _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32( vec32, perm32 );
}

__m256i bitSetAvx( __m256i source, uint8_t index )
{
    const __m256i oneBitVec = makeSingleBitMask( index );
    return _mm256_or_si256( source, oneBitVec );
}

bool bitTestAvx( __m256i source, uint8_t index )
{
    // Extract the 32-bit slice from the vector
    const __m256i perm32 = setLow( index / 32 );
    source = _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32( source, perm32 );
    const uint32_t scalar = (uint32_t)_mm256_cvtsi256_si32( source );

    // Test the specified bit; compilers should hopefully use BT instruction
    // https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bt
    const uint32_t bit = 1u << ( index % 32 );
    return 0 != ( scalar & bit );
}

Take a look at the assembly output made by GCC 14 compiler when asked to optimize for AMD Zen 3. As you see, these two pages of C++ compiled into just 12 instructions for bit set and 10 for bit test, without any branches or memory transactions.

Setbit can be 5 instructions (not counting loading a set1_epi32(1)) using set individual bit in AVX register (__m256i), need "random access" operator - https://godbolt.org/z/a7qGbcEPT .  All of them vector instructions vs. yours using more scalar integer, but all single-uop in-lane operations.  You could build a get out of this, using vptest instead of vpor.

@PeterCordes Yeah, but the code you have linked loads 2 vector constants from memory. I think that code will be faster when called from a tight loop, when the compiler inlines everything and has enough spare vector registers to for these two constants. Otherwise, my version which doesn’t do any loads going to be faster, despite more instructions.

If it's called in a loop at all, a vector load is fine since it'll be hot in L1d cache even if a compiler fails to keep it in a register.  (Later GCC likes to materialize the set1(1) constant with mov-immediate, which costs 3 instructions and would be worse in a loop.  And probably worse if it's already loading a different constant from the same cache line.)  But yes, for a one-off that runs very occasionally, or only at the end of a long loop that touches a lot of memory, avoiding any vector constants has value.

It would be possible to materialize a [0, 32, 64, ..., 224] vector constant (for use with vpsubd instead of vpaddd) from mov r64, imm64 / vmovd / vpmovzxbd, which is only more expensive than what GCC does for set1(1) in the 10-byte movabs vs. a 5-byte mov imm32.  And when it inlines, can be hoisted.  And of course these instructions have no input dependencies so don't contribute to the latency of this operation, very OoO exec friendly.  But if we wrote it as _mm_cvtsi64x_si128(...) and so on, compilers would constant-propagate, so current GCC is the worst of both worlds :/
